# How much should I pack inside a executable .JAR?

Tags: java, file, jar, io, executable-jar

I'm unsure if this would be more suitable for SuperUser, but I figured I'd went with StackOverflow.

Looking at an example of a game developed using Java, *Minecraft*, we see several resource files in the game's *AppData/.minecraft* folder. These are files such as **.OGG sound files**, basically files used to load content into the game, that weren't packed inside the *minecraft.jar* executable.

I'm working with Eclipse to develop Java applications, and I wonder, since you can import any kind of file into an Eclipse project, which would then be packed into an executable .jar upon export, what are the cons by packing a majority of the items, such as content, text files etc. into the project?
To decrease the size of the .jar?

I'd say, packing more things into a .jar would presume a bit more portability, *but* would result bit bigger size.

Perhaps my opinion wouldn't follow proper, and if so - why do Java developers want to, if they typically do, leave a lot of files beside the .JAR, for the .JAR to read? Especially static files (files that will not be modified or moved)?

Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is definitely the correct site for this over SuperUser.  In any case, the main benefit of putting the stuff outside is the fact that the files are the same between multiple versions, and having to download all the audio files between versions would be annoying.

Comment: The primary reason to put resources inside the jar is for self-containment.  This is important for executable jars, but note the distinction between those and jars that simply contain a class that provides an application entry point (main method).

Comment: There is no technical reason against having a large jar. However a sound file can be played by the system, whereas a sound resource would be more suited to be kept in memory and played from there: costly.